# Brackets, true, false understanding

Tags: javascript, php, obfuscation

Can anybody explain me why this javascript code alerts "47" ?

```
var component = +((!+[] + !![] + !![] + !![] + []) + (!+[] + !![] + !![] + !![] + !![] + !![] + !![]));
alert(component);
```

how those brackets, plus signs, etc return 47 at the end when I execute them ?

how to write this in PHP. I understand this is something with strings, booleans, etc.. but can't understand it ?

Comment: Why would you want to write this in PHP?

Comment: Try breaking it down operation by operation and figure out what each operation is doing (and have the rules of javascript implicit type conversions open while you do so). The browser console is good for this. I could do this for you, but I'm too lazy, and it's a good learning experience for you :) Plus this seems like the kind of silly exercise that would get assigned as a class assignment.

Comment: In JavaScript, false + false -> 0, false + true -> 1, true + true -> 2; the arrays (in most cases) are not actually used, except to be a source expression. ![] -> false, !![] -> true, !+[] -> true.

Comment: ![]==0, !![]==1. adding one 7 times = 7...

Comment: http://patriciopalladino.com/blog/2012/08/09/non-alphanumeric-javascript.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
false       =>  ![] 

true        =>  !![] 

undefined    =>  [][[]] 

NaN          =>  +[![]] 

0            =>  +[] 

1            =>  +!+[] 

2            =>  !+[]+!+[] 

10           =>  [+!+[]]+[+[]] 

Array        =>  [] 

Number      =>  +[] 

String       =>  []+[] 

Boolean      =>  ![] 

Function     =>  []["filter"] 

eval         =>  []["filter"]["constructor"]( CODE )()

window      =>  []["filter"]["constructor"]("return this")()
```

Just about anything javascript can be turned into incredibly hard to read crap if you use those conversions.  It is stupid, but it can be done.

So take the 10 for example:

```
[+!+[]]+[+[]]
```

This is really two components:

```
[+!+[]]

and

[+[]]
```

This is just `[1]` and `[0]`.  But if we add them together, they are cast to strings, so we get "1" + "0" which gives us "10".

For your question:

```
+((!+[] + !![] + !![] + !![] + []) + (!+[] + !![] + !![] + !![] + !![] + !![] + !![]));
```

I'll break down the 4 component:

```
(!+[] + !![] + !![] + !![] + [])

true + true + true + true + array
```

which if you run it in the console, gives you 4.  The last [] does nothing for this part, but it forces the typecast to string, which is important for the next part.

Then, the next one becomes

```
true + true + true + true + true + true + true
```

which gives you 7.

So you get 4 + [] + 7, which makes "47" since the `+ [] +` forces the typecast to string.

To do it in PHP, you could do something like:

```
$x = (![] + ![] + ![] + ![]) . (![] + ![] + ![] + ![] + ![] + ![] + ![]);
//$x is now 47
```

Comment: Your native constructors are all lacking a `.constructor`. `[] !== Array`

Comment: Also, could you please be more specific about the line in the question? The `10` example, with a bit explanation, could be easily extended to make `47`

Comment: @olive_tree: No, it's way too early for accepting now. He should wait a bit with that and then choose the highest-quality one.

Comment: Sure, he did comment above those- also personally I find this answer to be most clear.

Comment: I understood the meanings, but how to write this in PHP as a $component variable to return 47 ?

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, `false + false -> 0`, `false + true -> 1`, `true + true -> 2`. The arrays are not used directly, except to be a source expression: `![] -> false`, `!![] -> true`, `!+[] -> true`, and `number + [] -> "number"`.

Thus we have (where t = true, f = false):

```
+((!+[] + !![] + !![] + !![] + []) + (!+[] + !![] + !![] + !![] + !![] + !![] + !![]));

+((t + t + t + t + []) + (t + t + t + t + t + t + t));

+((4 + []) + (7));
```

Now, see `4 + []`? That is handled as a string *concatenation* after conversions, and the result is "4" so:

```
+(("4") + (7))

+("4" + 7)

+("47")

47
```

I have no idea how this particular piece would translate to PHP.

Answer (score 1):

In JS:

- [] is an empty array
- ! means "not" in js, so if the value after it is true, then it
  becomes false and vice versa
- "+" in front of a boolean in js is a unary plus. It converts the
  value to an integer. [How do I convert a string into an integer in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133770/how-do-i-convert-a-string-into-an-integer-in-javascript)

The JS elements:

```
+[]: 0
![]: true
+![]: 1
!![]: false
+!![]: 0
```

In PHP:

- array() is an empty array
- ! means "not", so it converts to true to false and vice versa as in js
- (int) will typecast the boolean to an integer, like the + did in js.

The PHP Elements:

```
(int) empty(array()): 0
empty(array()): true
(int) empty(array()): 1
!empty(array()): false
(int) !empty(array()): 0
```

Now add it all up. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

There is various things need to analysis one by one, let's start:

suppose

```
var p = [];
console.log(typeof p) // => object (array) 
console.log(p) //=> []
```

Again,

```
var p = +[]; 
console.log(typeof p) //=> number 
console.log(p) //=> 0
```

Again,

```
var p = ![]; 
console.log(typeof p); //boolean
console.log(p); //false
```

Again,

```
var p =   !![];
console.log(typeof p); // boolean
console.log(p); //true
```

Again,

```
var p =   !+[];
console.log(typeof p);  //boolean
console.log(p);  //true
```

Now

```
boolean true ==> 1
boolean false ==> 0
```

So,

```
var p =  (
   !+[] + 
   !![] + 
   !![] + 
   !![] + 
   []
 );
console.log(typeof p); //string 
console.log(p); // 4
```

And

```
var p = (
    !+[] + 
    !![] + 
    !![] + 
    !![] + 
    !![] + 
    !![] + 
    !![]
  );
console.log(typeof p); //number 
console.log(p);  // 7
```

Finally:

```
var p = +(
 (
   !+[] + 
   !![] + 
   !![] + 
   !![] + 
   []
 ) + 

  (
    !+[] + 
    !![] + 
    !![] + 
    !![] + 
    !![] + 
    !![] + 
    !![]
  )

);
console.log(typeof p); //Number
console.log(p); //47
```

You can write the same in php with array, boolean ( negation !) .

Answer (score 0):

```
+[] -> 0 //Because + converts all other javascript types to numbers
!+[] -> true //Because ! converts 0 to true
![] -> false //Empty array is true 
!![] -> true //Because ![] is false
```

`(!+[] + !![] + !![] + !![] + []) -> true+true+true+true+""="4"`

`+` converts **Boolean** value to **1** if it is `true`, and **0** if it is `false`.`

And **this is a string value**,because `Number`+`Empty object` creates a **string**, because an **Empty Object** can't convert to `Number` it converts to a `String`. And as we know `Number+String->String`.

**As a result:** `(!+[] + !![] + !![] + !![] + [])` **is the same as** `"4"`

In the same way

```
(!+[] + !![] + !![] + !![] + !![] + !![] + !![]) -> true+true+true+true+true+true+true = 7 //this is a Number, because Boolean value converts to a Number: either 0 or 1
```

And finally

```
"4"+7=47
```